# JavaFX Table putting comma in between numbers after updating

Tags: javafx

When I am editing a cell, it just shows the numbers. But as soon as i hit enter, it converts to comma separated value. When i am editing the cell, the commas disappear and i can edit the number. when i am editing a cell, all the cell in the column removes the commas

```
public void editData(final TableColumn col, final int rowIndex, final List colName)
    {
        for (final var columnMap: _columnMap.entrySet())
        {
            if (columnMap.getKey().equals(col.getText()))
            {
                columnMap.getValue().setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
                columnMap.getValue().setOnEditCommit((EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<PointToPointTableData, String>>) t ->
                {
                    highlightRow(colName, rowIndex);
                    if (t.getNewValue() != null && !t.getNewValue().isEmpty())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            final double newValue = Double.parseDouble(t.getNewValue());
                            final boolean inRange = _factory.checkValidInput(col.getText(), newValue);
                            if (inRange)
                                setAxisValue(t, col);
                            else
                            {
                                final Pair<Double, Double> range = _factory.getInputRange(col.getText());

                                if (range != null)
                                    GuiUtil.showAlert("Input is out of range. It must be between "
                                            + formatter.format(range.getFirst()) + " and "
                                            + formatter.format(range.getSecond()));
                                else
                                    GuiUtil.showAlert("Input range is not set.");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                            GuiUtil.showAlert("Invalid Input. Input must be a numeric value.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GuiUtil.showAlert("Invalid Input. Input cannot be empty.");
                    }

                    System.out.println("ASDASDASDASDDASD: " + t.getNewValue());
                });
            }
            else
            {
                columnMap.getValue().setCellFactory(createHighlightCellFactory(colName, columnMap, rowIndex));
            }
        }
        _indexColumn.setCellFactory(createIndexCellFactory(rowIndex));
    }
```

```
private void setAxisValue(final TableColumn.CellEditEvent<PointToPointTableData, String> t,
                              final TableColumn<PointToPointTableData, String> col)
    {
        t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setColumn(col.getText(),
                                                                                 t.getNewValue());
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

I was expecting two things, remove commas entirely. only remove commas from the cell being edited.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with a simple table view using `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` on JavaFX 21.0.2. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].